# Number of rows between two hours regardless of date

Tags: oracle

I want to get all records between two consecutive hours. But I want to show all rows regardless of day, month or year.

I have an approximation but it doesn't works when the range of hours cross to new day (23:00 to 01:00).

```
SELECT * 
from     
 dba_hist_sqlstat stat,
 dba_hist_snapshot snap
where snap.instance_number = stat.instance_number and stat.snap_id=snap.snap_id and SQL_ID='f2kmv0hafq9c3' 
 AND TO_CHAR(snap.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'HH24MISS') >= 000000 AND TO_CHAR(snap.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'HH24MISS') <= 040000    
ORDER BY 1
```

Regards

Comment: So, does what you have work with "normal" 2-hour ranges: `AND TO_CHAR(snap.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'HH24MISS') >= '020000'
    AND TO_CHAR(snap.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'HH24MISS')  < '040000'` ?

Comment: This should work for crossing-midnight ranges: `AND ( TO_CHAR(snap.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'HH24MISS') >= '230000'
       OR TO_CHAR(snap.BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME,'HH24MISS')  < '010000'
        )`